# Python - Package installed into site-packages but won't import

Tags: python, python-3.6, xlrd

I have installed the package xlrd but am unable to import it when using my IDE (Rodeo).

Having looked at a few questions on stackoverflow, I still can't work out why I get the following error:
ImportError: No module named 'xlrd'

The xlrd folder in site-packages does have an **__init__.py** file.

Additionally, if I attempt to import xlrd using the Command Prompt, I get no errors. But I do when using Rodeo.

While trying to solve this problem, I have added the file location of site-packages (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages) to the System Variables "Path", although I'm not sure what this does or if it's relevant.

I am using Python 3.6 and am a Python beginner so would appreciate any answers to be described in a basic way!

Comment: It's possible that your IDE has a python interpreter permanently running in the background, which was started before you installed the module. Have you tried restarting your IDE?

Comment: @Rawing, thank you for the suggestion, I have tried restarting but sadly this hasn't fixed the problem